# C++ Inheritance member functions using static variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-members

I am trying to convert some Python classes into c++ but am having some trouble. I have a Base class which has a class (static) variable and a method which returns it. I also have a derived class which overrides the class (static) variable like so,

In Python:

```
class Base:
   class_var = "Base"
   @classmethod
   def printClassVar(cls):
      print cls.class_var

class Derived(Base):
   class_var = "Derived"

d = Derived()
d.printClassVar()
```

which prints out the desired derived class variable, "Derived". Any idea how I can get the same functionality in c++? I have tried but end up getting the class variable of the Base class.

In c++

```
class Base
{
public:
    static void printStaticVar(){cout << s_var << endl;}
    static string s_var;
};
string Base::s_var = "Base";

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    static string s_var;
};
string Derived::s_var = "Derived";

void main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.printStaticVar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a virtual function which returns a reference to the static member:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void printStaticVar() {cout << get_string() << endl;}
    static string s_var;
    virtual string const& get_string() { return Base::s_var; }
};
string Base::s_var = "Base";

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    static string s_var;
    virtual string const& get_string() { return Derived::s_var; }
};
string Derived::s_var = "Derived";

void main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.printStaticVar();
}
```

Note that `printStaticVar` shouldn't be static.

---

You could also make the string `static` local inside the getter:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void printStaticVar() {cout << get_string() << endl;}
    virtual string const& get_string() { 
        static string str = "Base";
        return str;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual string const& get_string() { 
        static string str = "Derived";
        return str;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.printStaticVar();
}
```

Comment: Or, instead of having a static variable at all, simply return a constant, in this example. However that may not be suitable for all solutons.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility might be:

```
class Base
{
  const std::string var;
public:
  Base(std::string s="Base") : var(s) {}
  void printVar() { std::cout << var << std::endl }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(std::string s="Derived") : Base(s) {}
};
```